# Estilos CSS para validación de input con Sweet Alert

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap

Este código tiene un efecto en el *input* con *CSS* para que se vea bonita y se valida con el *required* de forma normal, pero cuando uso *Javascript* y *Sweet Alert* para que funcione necesito quitarle el *required* al *input*, pero pierdo el efecto, no baja la etiqueta.

Funciona bien la página, pero ¿hay alguna forma de que funcione quitando *required* sin perder el efecto de la etiqueta?.

```js
$("#enviar" ).submit(function( event ) {
var parametros = $(this).serialize();    
var data = new FormData(this);
if($("#nombre").val() == "") { 
swal({
        icon: 'info',
        text: 'Ingrese nombres',
        closeModal: false
        }).then(function() {
        swal.close();
        $('#nombre').focus();
}); 
return false;
}
});
```

```css
     @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(-135deg, #c850c0, #4158d0);
}
.wrapper{
  width: 450px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.wrapper .input-data{
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper .input-data input{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid silver;
}
.input-data input:focus ~ label,
.input-data input:valid ~ label{
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #4158d0;
}
.wrapper .input-data label{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  color: grey;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.input-data .underline{
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
.input-data .underline:before{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #4158d0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}
.input-data input:focus ~ .underline:before,
.input-data input:valid ~ .underline:before{
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PAGINA</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
  <body>
<form id="enviar">    
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="input-data">
        <input type="text" id="nombre" required>
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <label>Nombres</label>
      </div>
      <br>
      <input class="btn btn-success" name="registrar" type="submit" value="Registrar">
    </div>
</form>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En CSS elimina `, .input-data input:valid ~ label`, porque sin `required` el campo automáticamente está validado y toma esa regla.

Ahora solo se necesita una nueva clase `isValid` y una función para analizar el valor del campo cada que se modifique para agregar o quitar la clase:

```js
$("#enviar" ).submit(function( event ) {
var parametros = $(this).serialize();    
var data = new FormData(this);
if($("#nombre").val() == "") { 
swal({
        icon: 'info',
        text: 'Ingrese nombres',
        closeModal: false
        }).then(function() {
        swal.close();
        $('#nombre').focus();
}); 
return false;
}
});

// Asignar evento para ver los cambios en el campo
$('#nombre').on('change', function() {
   // Cambia la comparación para realizar una validación adecuada
   if($(this).val() == '') {
       // No es válido, quitar clase
       $(this).removeClass('isValid');
   } else {
       // Es válido, agregar clase para mover etiqueta
       $(this).addClass('isValid');
   }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(-135deg, #c850c0, #4158d0);
}
.wrapper{
  width: 450px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.wrapper .input-data{
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper .input-data input{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid silver;
}
.input-data input:focus ~ label,
input-data input.isValid ~ label {
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #4158d0;
}
.wrapper .input-data label{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  color: grey;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.input-data .underline{
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
.input-data .underline:before{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #4158d0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}
.input-data input:focus ~ .underline:before,
.input-data input.isValid ~ .underline:before{
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PAGINA</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
  <body>
<form id="enviar">    
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="input-data">
        <input type="text" id="nombre">
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <label>Nombres</label>
      </div>
      <br>
      <input class="btn btn-success" name="registrar" type="submit" value="Registrar">
    </div>
</form>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Habrá una forma de asignar a todo los tipo imput sin necesidad de poner el id

Comment: Creo que perdió el efecto en el label

Comment: Sí, solo agrega una clase a todos los _input_ que quieras que aplique, por ejemplo: `class="validar"` y en Javascript cambias la función del evento: `$(.validar').on('change', function() { ... });`

Comment: No, sigue el efecto de la etiqueta, cuando el campo está vacío se baja. Se sube cuando el campo recibe el foco o no está vacío.

Comment: Me refiero al efecto de la linea azul en la caja

Comment: Listo, abajo había que remplazar `:valid` por `.isValid` y ya funciona.

Comment: Muchas Gracias mi amigo justo así necesitaba